# Outputting a Linked List

Tags: java

I can't quite figure out how I'm supposed to get to the next value. Sofar I figured out how to get the first given value but not the remaining. Overall this is meant to be done using recursion. I mainly am trying to get a better understanding of how to go through the values given to IntNode class which is given to printLinkedList as headNode.

Example:

Input: 4 9 8 7 6

Output: 9, 8, 7, 6,

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {

    /* TODO: Write recursive printLinkedList() method */
    public static void printLinkedList(IntNode headNode){

        //This just prints the current value
        headNode.printData();
        headNode.insertAfter(headNode.getNext());
        headNode.printData();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size;
        int value;

        size = scnr.nextInt();
        value = scnr.nextInt();
        IntNode headNode = new IntNode(value); // Make head node as the first node
        IntNode lastNode = headNode;      // Node to add after
        IntNode newNode = null;           // Node to create

        // Insert the second and the rest of the nodes
        for (int n = 0; n < size - 1; ++n) {
            value = scnr.nextInt();
            newNode = new IntNode(value);
            lastNode.insertAfter(newNode);
            lastNode = newNode;
        }

        // Call printLinkedList() with the head node
        printLinkedList(headNode);
    }
}
```

```
public class IntNode {
    int dataVal;
    private IntNode nextNodeRef; // Reference to the next node

    // Constructor
    public IntNode(int value) {
        this.dataVal = value;
        this.nextNodeRef = null;
    }

    // Insert a new node after the current node
    public void insertAfter(IntNode nodeLoc) {
        IntNode tmpNext;

        tmpNext = this.nextNodeRef;
        this.nextNodeRef = nodeLoc;
        nodeLoc.nextNodeRef = tmpNext;
    }

    // Get location pointed by nextNodeRef
    public IntNode getNext() {
        return this.nextNodeRef;
    }

    // Print the node's data
    public void printData() {
        System.out.printf("%d, ", this.dataVal);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `printLinkedList` function with below code:

```
public static void printLinkedList(IntNode headNode) {
    //check if the node is null or not
    if (headNode != null) {
        headNode.printData();
        printLinkedList(headNode.getNext()); // recursively call the method with next node as value
    }
}
```

Only change that is required to be done is to call the `printLinkedList` method with the next node. Read more about recursion [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursion-in-java/) and linked list [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-1-introduction/)